# Excel VBA Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Public Function get_workbook() As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fd.Title = "Please select the file."
    fd.Show
    get_workbook = fd.SelectedItems(1)
End Function
```

This works. However, if the user closes the dialog box once opened, there is an:
"Invalid procedure call or argument" error thrown.

How would I go about handling this error?
So for example, rather than that error being thrown, the function simply exits.

EDIT:

I use this code to get the user to open a file which also works.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_workbook(), ReadOnly:=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in an error handler. I used a select case so you can add other errors should they occur.

```
Public Function get_workbook() As String
    On Error GoTo errcatch 
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fd.Title = "Please select the file."
    fd.Show
    get_workbook = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    on error goto 0
    Exit Function 'Stop code from going into error handler without an error
errcatch:
    Select Case Err.Number 'Do something based on error number
        Case 5  
            on error goto 0
            Exit Function
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! When I cancel the dialog box, I get an error on this code:

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(get_workbook(), ReadOnly:=True)

The error is: "Run time error '1004':
Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved.. etc etc"

Comment: That's because you didn't return anything, the function just ends. You will need another error handler in the calling sub/function or an ```if``` statement checking for an empty string.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, working around it now! Cheers Warcupine!

Comment: Might be worth adding `On Error Resume Next` before exiting function

Comment: @zac that wouldn't do anything the error he was getting is in a different sub, and on error resume next should only be used in a few edge cases it just hides the error, it doesn't handle it.

Comment: :) Sorry, my bad, I meant `On Error Goto 0`.. my excuse is, it's friday

Comment: @Zac Wouldn't the scope immediately change making it superfluous? (I don't actually know if that's how it works but i suspect it is)

Comment: If yo don't set it back to `On Error Goto 0`, it means that when you run code next time (possibly a different code) your error handling is still set to your last state. That could throw unwanted/spurious errors. It's always good practice to set it back if you change your error state

Comment: I called it **error state**, it's actually error handling :)